# Meromorphic functions proportionality

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f(z)$ and $g(z)$ be two meromorphic functions with the same zeros and poles. How can we proof that they  must be proportional to one another.

Comment: That would be very restrictive. Do you know that it is true? If this is true it means for example that $k\prod_{n\in \mathbb Z} (z-2n\pi i) = \exp(z)-1, k\in \mathbb C$. And since the series Taylor expansion anywhere converges all over $\mathbb C$ we should be able to disprove it by comparison ( if it is not true ).

Comment: i found it here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_determinant

Comment: It is claimed that Liouvilles theorem is enough to prove it. Do you know of the theorem? That all bounded entire holomorphic functions are constant. There is probably a link on wikipedia.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean meromorphic on $\mathbb{C}$, the claim is false: Take for example $f(z) = z$ and $g(z) = ze^z$.

If you mean meromorphic on the Riemann sphere, $f$ and $g$ are in fact rational functions. Can you take it from there?